# Drupal 8: Notify message is not translated

Tags: php, email, drupal, localization, drupal-modules

I am using **message** & **message_notify** contrib module.

I have enabled language module, It has By default English (en), Korean (ko), Japanese (ja).

I have translate below template in Japanese language as well.

```
  $language = 'ja';
  $message = Message::create([
    'template' => 'sample_template',
    'langcode' => $language
  ]);

  $message->setLanguage($language);

  $message->save();

  $message = $message->getTranslation($language);

  $notifier = \Drupal::service('message_notify.sender');
  $result = $notifier->send($message);
```

When I am trying to send email it always sending in English, rather than Japanese.

Am I missing something in Language configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Drupal\message_notify\MessageNotifier` expects to be passed an object that implements `Drupal\message\MessageInterface`.

```
public function send(
    MessageInterface $message, array $options = [], $notifier_name = 'email')
```

In `Drupal\message_notify\Plugin\Notifier\Email` source, the preference language is used for rendering the message when `language override` option is set to `FALSE`.

```
    if (!$this->configuration['language override']) {
      $language = $account->getPreferredLangcode();
    }
    else {
      $language = $this->message->language()->getId();
    }
```

In `options` array, configure language to be overridden so that the message is rendered in the set language.

```
$message->setLanguage($language);
$result = $notifier->send($message, ['language override' => TRUE]);
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct solution. It is working for one message sent in one language to all recipient. How to send messages to the preferred language of each user?

Comment: The default language is the drupal account's preferred language and you should leave it that way if that is the behavior you desire. This question asks about overriding the language of a notification and that can only be done by explicit setting `language override` option when the message is sent.

Comment: you are right... I overlooked the original question. I came here because I can not get the messages in the preferred language of each user... it is not what is asked here. sorry for that.

Comment: If you have any hint, I have asked a question with my problem there: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292467/message-from-message-stack-not-translated-into-the-preferred-language-of-the-r